# "Serial transmit complete"-Interrupt RS485 [BeagleBoneBlack - Angstrom]

Tags: c++, linux, beagleboneblack, angstrom-linux, rs485

I am developing an application on a BeagleBoneBlack. Embedded linux is quite new for me =/

The problem I am facing is that I want to implement a RS485 communication,
I wrote a piece of C++-Code by using the SeriaLib-Library, for the moment a dedicated GPIO is used to toggle the direction of the RS485 interface. All has been fine till this point.

To write a message the function write is used a below

```
write(fd,Message,Lenght);
```

The only problem is to toggle the DIRECTION-Pin immediately after the last byte is written on the BUS =(

While developing on microcontrollers its no problem to react on various interrupts and so on.

Is there any solution - deep in the kernel? - to toggle a pin DIRECT after the succesful transmit of the message?

Comment: Well it's hardly "embedded" - you have a full desktop OS on there! It's just _different_ hardware than you're used to.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - you really have no idea what installation is on there.  Uncounted tiny, clearly "embedded" devices have linux *kernels* these days (pocket routers, SD cards that do wifi upload, etc), being a "full desktop OS" or not depends on the *unspecified userspace*.  This problem really comes down to the use of a multitasking operating system, on hardware that may or may not support a transmission complete interrupt.

Answer (score 2):

Normally on a *small* microcontroller upon fifoing the last character you can either enable a transmission complete interrupt, or just busy wait on the transmit complete flag in your send routine, then disable the driver.

However, some heavier-weight MCU's don't have a transmission complete interrupt, and a multitasking OS may *dislike* busy waiting (and introduce undesired latency if you yield between polls).  Two ways of dealing with that come to mind.

1. Since you have a driver to disable, it sounds like you have a single bidirectional pair, and will *receive everything you transmit*.  Coupled with some state tracking, you could then use the *receive* interrupt to know that your last character has been sent, and disable the driver.  (Also handle RX errors if somebody else jams the bus)
2. Determine the baudrate-dependent time from enqueueing the last character until transmission complete, and set a timer interrupt for that amount of time, then disable the driver in the ISR.

Comment: Hello Chris, you are right with the single bidirectional signal data line. It is a 2-wire RS485.  
To your suggested points (1) and (2).   
(1) Could be a solution, but i dont want spent too much intelligence into the transmit algorithm.  
(2) This is exactly the way i am doing right now - this can't a proper solution.     

My further thoughts are:  
- Usage of the UART1-RTS to enable the transceiver. I guess this should have the same effect like a DIRECTION-PIN.  
--> Is there a method to the RTS-state in my application? I really have to know the time of a complete message transmission.

Comment: I suggest you spend the time to work out the state logic, or if that is too much build a hardware driver timeout.